# Why does an Eclipse builder return a "file_get_contents() ... Permission denied" warning for a PHP script but not the command line?

Tags: php, eclipse, less.php

**Background:** I'm trying to use [Less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php) to compile my project's LESS code into CSS in an Eclipse builder.

When I install and run less.php with the command `lessc`, it correctly compiles my LESS into CSS with no visible errors:
[image: results of running in command line]

However, when I set up `lessc` to run as a builder in Eclipse:
[image: Eclipse builder configuration]

I get a `Warning: file_get_contents(...): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...` message:
[image: results of running in Eclipse]

Stranger still, a moment later, a newly-compiled CSS file always appears. So this script seems to be working, but **it always spits out this warning that I don't see when I run the same script in the command line.**

- What causes the "permission denied" error on localhost?
- Why would it appear when Eclipse runs the script but not when it's run from the command line?
- Could my Eclipse builder configuration be missing something?

I'm running

- [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) 1.8.2
- Windows 7
- PHP 5.4.27
- Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

2 guesses:

- Eclipse has not the right to read the file/folder
- In the php.ini is something like this

  disable_functions=file_get_contents